# Multiplying two columns from two different tables - SQL

Tags: sql

I'm trying to multiply two columns called **population** and **populationgrowth** from two different tables called **country** and **population**.

The two tables are:
**Country**
*name* --   *population*

**Population**
*name* -- *populationgrowth*

I want the end result to look like:

**Growth**
population1*populationgrowth1
population2*populationgrowth2
etc..

I have tried this

```
select((select population from country) *  
  (select populationgrowth 
  from population));
```

but i get an error called: ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression.

Best wishes

EDIT - thanks a lot  guys, very helpful :)

Comment: HINT: Use `JOIN`.

Comment: The `join` answers below are accurate. Depending on your data, you might want to note the difference between an inner join and an outer join; and if you go with an outer join, remember that anything multiplied by `null` will return `null`. You may want to ensure that there is a default value of "1" in the event of a null. You could have a calculation like this: `isnull(c.population, 1) * isnull(p.population, 1)`. Note that `isnull()` depends on which database RDBMS you're using.

Comment: In relation to your edit: don't forget to accept an answer if your problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need a Join:

```
SELECT a.name, (a.population * b.populationgrowth) multiplication
  FROM Country a, Population b
 WHERE a.name = b.name
```

Comment: Use proper `JOIN`.  It's been around for over 20 years.

Comment: Thanks, Eric! The thing about it is that I never found evidence to show one way is more efficient that other. I'm gonna do research.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to join the tables together to perform the calculation.
Something like this:

```
SELECT c.name,c.population*p.populationgrowth AS Growth
FROM Country c
    INNER JOIN [Population] p
        ON c.name = p.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below query . Basic rule in sql , first you have to join both table on common key and then select the column with whatever action you need

```
Select c.Population*p.Populationgrowth output
       from 
     Country c 
     join Population p on c.name=p.name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code sample to figure this out

```
create table Country (name varchar(100), population int);
create table Population (CountryName varchar(100), PGrowth decimal(5,3));
go

insert into Country (name, population) values ('Canada', 35000000), ('USA', '350000000');
insert into Population (CountryName, PGrowth) Values ('Canada', 0.02), ('USA', 0.025);
go
select c.name, Growth=c.population*p.PGrowth
from country c
inner join Population p
on p.CountryName = c.name;
```

The result is as follows

[image]